# Javascript undifined error while using dataset with django templates

Tags: javascript, html, django

I get **undefined error** while using JS dataset to try to get data from a django template i cant fix it, can anyone provide a solution.
The index.html template

```
<div id="currentUser1" data-currentUser="1"></div>
```

For the JS code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    
    let currentuser2 = document.querySelector('#currentUser1').dataset.currentUser;
    console.log(currentuser2)

});
```

The out on the browser

```
undefined      network.js:4:13
```

Thats the error I get, and as for the console everything is okay with no errors.

Comment: That's not an error. That's the output of your `console.log` saying that `currentuser2` is undefined. Try checking to see if the `dataset` you're accessing in the line above has data in the format you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataset properties are normalized to all lowercase for single words within `data-` attributes and camelCase for hyphenated ones, regardless of whether you use caps in the name or not

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const {currentuser, fooBar} = document.querySelector('#currentUser1').dataset
      
    console.log('currentuser =', currentuser)
    console.log('fooBar =', fooBar)

});
```

```html
<div id="currentUser1" data-currentUser="1" data-foo-bar="woohoo"></div>
```